# jQuery function is returning undefined

Tags: jquery, json, function

I want to write a simple function that will display an alert after sending the form, but I'm doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {

    var alert_container  = $('<div class="alert"></div>');
    var alert = {
        "success": "Success",
        "error":  "Error"
    };

    function show_message(msg) {

        alert_container
            .addClass(msg)
            .append('<p>'+alert.msg+'</p>');

        alert_container.insertBefore($("form")).hide().fadeIn(300);

    }

    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        show_message('success');
    });

});
```

This code returns to me undefined inside alert box, but if i check **console.log(alert.success)** returns correct value which is "Success". What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.append('<p>'+alert.msg+'</p>');
```

`alert.msg` does not exist here as it'll try and resolve .`msg`, not as an array property.

Try: `.append('<p>'+alert[msg]+'</p>');`